# Store all queries inside a module?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a quick question about VBNET, I'm currently using VS 2012 Express, and Microsoft Access as my database.

My question is, how do I put my queries in a module instead of put the queries in the form itself?
Let's say I have this function in frmStock :

frmStock :

```
Public Sub FillCategory(ByVal Key As String, ByVal Txt As String, ByVal N As TreeNode)
    Dim TD As TreeNode

    If N Is Nothing Then
        TD = tvCategory.Nodes.Add(Key, Txt)
    Else
        TD = N.Nodes.Add(Key, Txt)
    End If

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Category WHERE Category_Parent = ?", conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Category_Parent", Key)

    Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Do While dr.Read()
        FillCategory(dr("Category_ID"), dr("Category_Name"), TD)
    Loop
    dr.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
End Sub
```

I want to move

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Category WHERE Category_Parent = ?", conn)
```

into a module instead.

I tried doing :

```
Module queryCollection

    Public getCategoryParent As New OleDbCommand( _
            "SELECT * FROM Category WHERE Category_Parent = ?", conn)

End Module
```

And modifed my FillCategory function to :

```
Public Sub FillCategory(ByVal Key As String, ByVal Txt As String, ByVal N As TreeNode)
    Dim TD As TreeNode

    If N Is Nothing Then
        TD = tvCategory.Nodes.Add(Key, Txt)
    Else
        TD = N.Nodes.Add(Key, Txt)
    End If

    getCategoryParent.Parameters.AddWithValue("Category_Parent", Key)

    Dim dr = getCategoryParent.ExecuteReader

    Do While dr.Read()
        FillCategory(dr("Category_ID"), dr("Category_Name"), TD)
    Loop
    dr.Close()
    getCategoryParent.Dispose()
End Sub
```

UPDATE :
Some Screen shot for my problem :

My database :
http://puu.sh/39CMV.PNG

BEFORE moving out my query into module :
http://puu.sh/39D0M.PNG

AFTER moving out my query into module :
puu.sh/39CVV.PNG

It seem like only execute once(?) Why is this and what is the proper way of declaring my queries in a module?

I actually have tons of queries, I want to store them into one place for a more organized coding.

Comment: Do you really need to store queries?  Can't you use something like LINQ to SQL or LINQ to EF instead?  It'd be much better than having string literal queries in your code.

Comment: @DoctorJones , Hi thanks for your reply, I have not yet come across LINQ yet, and I'm using Microsoft Access as my database. I want to store all my queries into a module is mainly because there are way too many queries in my coding, it look so messy, I need to organized it.

Comment: I'd highly recommend looking at LINQ to SQL.  It eliminates all of the string literal queries in your code and replaces them with strongly typed queries instead.  This means you'll catch spelling mistakes, etc at compile time instead of runtime, and makes your code easier to maintain.

Comment: @DoctorJones , thanks a lots for information, I'll look into LINQ later for optimization purposes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your modified `FillCategory` code you called the following but never saved the result:

```
getCategoryParent.Parameters.AddWithValue("Category_Parent", Key)
```

That created an `OleDbCommand` object but then it is immediately discarded.  You then call:

```
Dim dr = getCategoryParent.ExecuteReader
```

Which creates a second `OleDbCommand` object but without a parameter value.

Modify your code like:

```
Dim cmd = getCategoryParent.Parameters.AddWithValue("Category_Parent", Key)
Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

EDIT: The following will address both problems.

```
Dim cmd = getCategoryParent
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Category_Parent", Key)
Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

Previously the `cmd` variable was being `Infer`ed by VB to be a `OleDbParameter` object, which does not have the `ExecuteReader` method.  It was inferred this way because of the way it was called with the `.Parameters.AddWithValue("Category_Parent", Key)` code done inline.

With this change `cmd` is correctly set to a `OleDbCommand` variable, and now you can use the `AddParameter` method as many times as needed.

EDIT 2: 
`getCategoryParent` is currently defined as property on the module.  That means that the `getCategoryParent` method is executed once when the module is first instantiated, not once per loop.  Change that method to be a Function and now the code will be executed once per loop and your TreeView will be loaded as you expect.

```
Public Function getCategoryParent() As OleDbCommand
    Return New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Category WHERE Category_Parent = ?", conn)
End Function
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for pointing out my error. However I had just tried modified my code and it give me an error on the line :

Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteRead //‘ExecuteReader' is not a member of 'System.Data.Oledb.OleDbParameter'

Also another quick question, if I have more then one parameters to pass in, how do I pass it?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello , I tried your code and it work now :) But when I run the code it seem like only execute once, I will provide SS for more details :  
  
My database : [Database](http://puu.sh/39CMV.PNG)  
  
How my code work without moving out my query : [No Error](http://puu.sh/39D0M.PNG)  
  
How my code work after moving out my query : [Error](http://puu.sh/39CVV.PNG)  
  
How I call my FillCategory() function :  
FillCategory("1", "All Categories", Nothing)

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry if my comment confuse you, Stackoverflow don't allow line break in comment :(

Comment: @MiloJuakMuTou - See my edit to see why the query is only executing once.

Comment: Thanks!!! This is definitely what I'm searching today. Really thanks a lots for your answer, especially it come with explanation! :) Again, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

One approach I took with ASP.NET and Access was to save my SQL as files into a folder and load it using maybe a singleton like so:

```vb
Public Class FileHandler

    Public Shared Function LoadToString(ByVal pName As String) As String
        Dim rV As String
        Dim fio As StreamReader = File.OpenText(pName)
        rV = fio.ReadToEnd()
        fio.Close()
        Return rV
    End Function

End Class
```

Then call it from your code...

```vbs
...
dim sqlStr As String = FileHandler.LoadToString("sql/mySqlStatement.sql")
...
```

It's most likely not the best solution, though.  The main advantage to this is that you can modify the SQL on the fly without having to recompile your app.

An alternative would be to store your SQL statements as name value pairs in your web.config, but again, this isn't a very good solution.

Unless someone has a better suggestion with this, I think it's going to be a best of the worst choice!

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, I don't think storing queries in a text file is a good idea, this might be end up creating a lots of files if I have like, 20 queries?

Comment: Only 20?  You could load the ones you need at the start of the app.

Answer (score 0):

How about just put your SQL string on your module ..

```
Module queryCollection

    Public sCatParent As String = "SELECT * FROM Category WHERE Category_Parent = ?"

End Module
```

And you call it like ..

```
getCategoryParent As New OleDbCommand(sCatParent,conn)

getCategoryParent.Parameters.AddWithValue("Category_Parent", Key)

Dim dr = getCategoryParent.ExecuteReader
```

Comment: Hello, this work perfectly! However I'm still looking forward for a more effective code, also I wanted to know that why my code only execute one time. Anyway, thanks a lots :D I'll use this if there are no better answer <3